# NoMethodError on rspec test with boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run this rspec test:

```
  describe "quotes#approve action" do
    it "should successfully change boolean called approved to true" do
      get :approve
      expect(@quote).to have_attributes(:approved => true)
      expect(flash[:success]). to be_present
      expect(response).to redirect_to admin_path
    end
  end
```

which should call this code from the controller.

```
  def approve
    @quote.approved = true
  end
```

but when I run this test, I get this error

```
 Failure/Error: @quote.approved = true

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `approved=' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm fairly certain this has to do with my @quote variable being unassigned, but even before setting the boolean in the approve method doesn't seem to make a difference. As it's my first time running into a problem like this, I'm not quite sure where to start debugging it.

Edit:

I changed the rspec test to:

```
  describe "quotes#approve action" do
    it "should successfully change boolean called approved to true" do

      @quote = Quote.create(author: 'Test', saying: 'Hello!')
      get :approve, id: @quote.id
      expect(@quote).to have_attributes(:approved => true)
      expect(flash[:success]). to be_present
      expect(response).to redirect_to admin_path
    end
  end
```

and the controller code to:

```
  def approve
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote.approved = true
  end
```

This does seem to get me a step further, as I no longer get the NoMethodError, but I do now get a new error, which is:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(@quote).to have_attributes(:approved => true)

   expected #<Quote id: 102, author: "Test", saying: "Hello!", created_at: "2017-05-02 21:13:52", updated_at: "2017-05-02 21:13:52", approved: false> to have attributes {:approved => true} but had attributes {:approved => false}
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -:approved => true,
   +:approved => false,
```

I'm fairly certain that just means my controller code doesn't work properly, but I haven't been able to figure out what's going wrong yet.

Comment: your @quote is nil. Just print what is 'quote' inside the spec and check what is printed out when running rspec from the terminal.

Comment: Do you actually assign a value to `@quote` in your controller somewhere - in a before filter for example?

Comment: you are probably missing quote `id` param in the call to API: `get :approve, id: @quote.id`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Adding the id helped, as my code moves a little further now. I am stuck on the next issue though, which is the code (or test?) not working completely. I have edited the original post to show my new error. Thanks again for the help!